# How to create a physics body for an SKSpriteNode with an interior in Sprite Kit (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am currently making an iOS game in which a ball must bounce within a frame defined by the below image:

[image]

The game relies on the below method to automatically create and assign a physics body to the frame surrounding the game.

```
frame.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: frameTexture, size: frame.size)
```

This code, however, assigns a body that encompasses the outside of the image, rather than the interior, and thus treats the blank interior as a solid object. This, in turn, means that the ball cannot be inside the frame and is forced off the screen immediately after being spawned.

Is there any way to give a physics body an interior?

Another post here: [SpriteKit SKPhysicsBody with Inner Edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191957/spritekit-skphysicsbody-with-inner-edges) aims to do something similar, but does not involve automatic wrapping around a texture (hence the new question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **init(edgeLoopFrom:)** initializer to achieve inner edge friction. you can use this code below:

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    //Setup scene's physics body (setup the walls)
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)

    let back = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1")
    back.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    back.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 600)
    back.zPosition = -3
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -back.size.width/2, y: -back.size.height/2), size: back.size)
    back.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: rect)

    addChild(back)

    //Add Red ball "inside" the back sprite
    let red = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
    red.fillColor = .red
    red.strokeColor = .clear
    red.position = back.position
    red.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    red.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    red.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    red.zPosition = 1
    red.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    addChild(red)

    red.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 15))

}
```

please follow this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176454/programatically-create-constrained-region-of-physics-spritekit) and have a look to the answer given below.

i am providing a screenshot of my project [image: here]

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will attempt it soon before accepting :)